# Factory.create fails in Put context but not Post context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, mocha.js

I'm using factorygirl.   I'm still new, in particular to the testing aspect of rails.

When I descibe POST create I can create any number of Person objects without any issue.  I don't actually need to create one here as I normally just stub the valid? method of Person.  But for the purpose of resolving this issue I threw it in there.  Regardless of this Factory.create(:person) being in the POST create context (or how many times I use it there) it throws a non-descriptive error message when I use it in the PUT update context.

Additionally I have removed all validation from the model with  no change in the result.

I'm at a loss.

Lets just get the basics working:

```
describe PeopleController do
    describe "POST create" do
      describe "with valid params" do
        it "creates a person from params and renders persons/_form partial" do
            f = Factory.create(:person)
        #    f = Factory.create(:person)
        #    f = Factory.create(:person)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "PUT update" do
      describe "with valid params" do
        it "updates the requested person" do
            f = Factory.create(:person)        #error when running rake spec
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Error:

```
 Failure/Error: f = Factory.create(:person)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed:
```

Model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: It would help to see the factory definition file and the Person model code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your factory does not meet the validation requirements. In your factory definition, your factory should be able to pass all the validations. Otherwise, you have to explicitly fulfil them like :

```
f = Factory(:person, :attribute => value_that_passes_validation, ...)
```

EDIT (sequences):

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:username) { |n| "test#{n}" }
    f.password "1234567890"
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@test.com" }
end
```

Comment: I realize that the record is being deemed invalid.  The question is why does it seem this way only when testing in this context?  I can create any number in the POST create context but in the PUT update context the first one I create is always invalid.  And furthermore why does it not give a description of the error?  Hmmm

Comment: ahh, it must be that you do not use a sequence for your Factory. If you test for uniqueness, you have to use sequences. I'm pasting above

Comment: I don't think thats it.  There are no constraints in my model or on my database.   And even if that were the case it should tell me that in the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:  ...  line, but its blank.  Its probably something ridiculously stupid :)

Comment: But you get a validation error :O You do not have any validations on the Person model ? Can you paste your factory code as well ?